# library to convert pdf to image

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Hi friends I'm new to Codeigniter . In my new project i've a task to upload a pdf file and i've to convert it to an image . could any one suggest me solution is there is any library function to convert it and also get me some working code if possible . Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to extract images from PDF?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert (Split) PDF files into images with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/). Checkout this PHP library [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5846-PHP-Convert-PDF-documents-to-images-using-Ghostscript.html).

This class can be used to convert PDF documents to images using *Ghostscript*. It takes an uploaded PDF file and converts it into JPEG images using the *Ghostscript* program.

**NOTE:** The converted images are stored in files numbered according to the respective PDF document page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDFlib](https://github.com/imalhasaranga/PDFLib) php wrapper which I wrote sometime back, use it like below

```
$pdflib = new ImalH\PDFLib\PDFLib();
$pdflib->setPdfPath("pdf file path");
$pdflib->setOutputPath("output folder path");
$pdflib->setImageFormat(\ImalH\PDFLib\PDFLib::$IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG);
$pdflib->setDPI(300);
$pdflib->setPageRange(1,$pdflib->getNumberOfPages());
$pdflib->convert();
```

Answer (score -1):

with a simple google, i got this answer from somewhere else.

The image library supports ImageMagick if you have it installed on your server: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html

```
$config = array(
    'image_library' => 'imagemagick',
    'library_path' => 'imagemagick_file_path_goes_here',
    'source_image' => $pdf_path,
    'new_image' => $img_path,
    'maintain_ratio' => true,
    'width' => 365,
    'quality' => '100%',
   );

   $this->image_lib->initialize( $config );

   if ( $this->image_lib->resize( ) ) {
    $this->image_lib->clear( );
   }
```